# Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.1

Tags: android

How do resolve this error: Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnoJh.png)

Answer (score 2):

add configure properties in project's file `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

reference:https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I narrowed it down to the version of Glide I was using. If you're also using Glide, try updating your version to the latest (4.12.0). Updating fixed the issue for me.